# Measuring distance between two shapes

Tags: javascript, php, math, jpeg

*I have project to be done which is:*

We have a generator that needs 5 minutes to start working, and we have solar power station,
generator should start before sun set 5 minutes and shutdown on sunrise,

But since there are always clouds could come between the cells and the sun, we need to invent some device to estimate the distance between the visible clouds heading to the sun and calculate the time before this cloud cover the sun to send a signal to the generator starter 1 minute before it come between the cells and the sun.

**My idea** was to get sun tracker and fix a camera on it, this way i can center the sun in the image, then i can do some automated analysis to estimate the risk of each cloud to cover the sun.

**But** since there is no standard shape for the clouds it's almost impossible to calculate the distance between two shapes (Sun, Clouds).

Staring from the idea of centering the sun in the camera sight, what can i do to calculate the distance between the sun and the clouds using the frames coming from the camera?

P.S: The camera has a web access interface with frame by frame broadcast feature(JPG frames) and i'm a `PHP` Programmer (But still wide open to any other programming languages suggestions).

**Edit:**
As what @Nicky Smits's answer the process would be that i have to measure the distance difference between two frames to know the speed of that cloud and calculate it's arrival to the sun area in the picture.

[image: Frame 1]

In the following case the application should send a ping to some device so it can start the generator:

[image: Frame 2]

Comment: I really tried to understand it, but your problem is not clear for me. Could you clearify it? If you do, i'll take another look and fix it for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

If i interpret it right, you have to power supplies. The first is Solar Power, and the second is your generator. The generator takes 5 minutes to load, and since you do not want to be without a power supply, you want something to predict when your Solar Power supply is going to be rendered useless by clouds so you can start up your generator in advance accordingly. This beng said, there are a few things you can do. I do not know these things for sure, but these are ideas for you to try.

1. Make a function that finds the closest occurence of a cloud relative to the sun in your frame. (clouds are white, sun is yellow, sky is blue). Do this in a certain interval. If the cloud is getting closer, you can compute the speed at which the cloud is getting closer. (You could do this in pixel per second). You can estimate how long it would take for the cloud to cover up the sun if it were to do that.
2. Install a uv sensor. A cloud is never as compact as it looks. It has a lot of water molecules in it that block certain rays on the electromagnetic spectrum. We might be able to see most of the cloud, but around the cloud we see, there is a huge part we can not see, but a sensor can. So, set your sensor so it is aimed at the sun. And if the intensity lowers, in a certain speed or something, you can decide that a cloud is coming near, and how long it will probably take.

Good luck!

Comment: You got it right my friend and you just described my idea, now the problem is how to do it!
I mean is there any mathamatical way to measure the distance between to random area surfaces(Sun, Clouds) using PHP?

Comment: I think you would have to process a frame completely. Depending on the resolution, you would have to check a lot of pixels. Thats what i would do. Just index every pixel. You can find the outline of the sun that way. And you can find the outline of clouds. From there it should be doable with basic math skills.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem will be very difficult to solve using javascript and PHP. You say you are considering using others languages, then I'd recommend you look into openCV (Computer Vision).

Then using its java version for processing (http://www.processing.org/) could be the easiest way to get up and running quickly: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

You could then use a mixture of these different tutorials to obtain the results you are looking for:

http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration_square_chess/camera_calibration_square_chess.html#cameracalibrationsquarechessboardtutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html#background-subtraction

http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good suggestions, you can find a method for doing this with a webcam and the OpenCV computer vision library below. Using this technique, the error rate for the 20-second cloud forecast was 5.5%.

> **Cloud tracking with optical flow for short-term solar forecasting**
>
> A method for tracking and predicting cloud movement using ground based sky imagery is presented. Sequences of partial 
>   sky images, with each image taken one second apart with a size of 640 by 480 pixels, were processed to determine the time 
>   taken for clouds to reach a user defined region in the image or the Sun.
>
> The clouds were first identified by segmenting the 
>   image based on the difference between the blue and red colour channels, producing a binary detection image. Good features 
>   to track were then located in the image and tracked utilising the Lucas-Kanade method for optical flow.
>
> From the trajectory 
>   of the tracked features and the binary detection image, cloud signals were generated. The trajectory of the individual 
>   features were used to determine the risky cloud signals (signals that pass over the user defined region or Sun).
>
> Time to collision estimates were produced based on merging these risky cloud signals. Estimates of times up to 40 seconds were achieved with error in the estimate increasing when the estimated time is larger. The method presented has the potential for tracking clouds travelling in different directions and at different velocities.

http://solar-thermal.weblogs.anu.edu.au/files/2009/12/wood-bradley-2012-cloud-tracking.pdf